# represent real number as case of complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

my question is related  one  topic  ,which i would like to clarify using your help.so please help me to clarify this topic.problem is  following(actually it is just  my interest to clarify it)
in generally  we  can represent  any real number  as special  case of complex number,or  more corrected  this case is when imaginary part is zero,like

$5=5+0*i$

or if we compare form  $a+b*i$      -->  we get  $a=5$  and   $b=0$

but  because  rules  which  works in real  number domain  ,does not work in complex domain like 
$\log(z_1)+\log(z_2)=\log(z_1*z_2)$   does not  always  works unless  special case and also  $\sqrt{-1}*\sqrt{-1}$   does not equal  to   $\sqrt{-1*-1}$, could we  represent  real number in  the following form

$5=3+2*i^0$?

because  we know  that  every number in power 0(except  0)  is  1,is it also true for  imaginary $i$ as well?i am just curious it is not any homework,so please help me to clarify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to think about how the expression $z^a$ is defined for complex $z, a$. What you do is you pick any number $c$ such that $e^c = z$ (we write $c = \log z$), and then you put $z^a = e^{ca}$. Note that there are usually many possible values for $z^a$, since there are many possible values of $c$. In your case, though, no mather what number $c$ you pick for $e^c = i$, you'll have $i^0 = e^{c \cdot 0} = e^0 = 1$, so indeed $5 = 2 + 3 i^0$, because $i^0 = 1$.

Comment: thanks very much.i was not sure  about this

Comment: because complex numbers  have some constraints rules then real numbers.i wanted to know this fact